# gulp.js Plugin uncss can't be installed

Tags: gulp, gulp-uncss

I want to install/use the Gulp-Plugin uncss (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-un-css/) as my very first gulp-"try".

I therefore installed npm and Gulp successfully globally with the `CLI version 3.9.1`. I also installed the uncss-plugin with `npm install gulp-uncss --save-dev` and with `sudo npm install gulp-uncss --save-dev`.

At the end of that, I get the same message within the terminal:

```
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/project/front/node_modules/gulp-uncss/node_modules/uncss/node_modules/phridge/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/lib/index.js:5:33)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
npm ERR! phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs-prebuilt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls phantomjs-prebuilt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "gulp-uncss" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/me/project
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/Users/me/project/node_modules/gulp-uncss/node_modules/uncss/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/async/node_modules/lodash/throttle.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "gulp-uncss" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/me/project
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
npm ERR! path /Users/me/project/node_modules/gulp-uncss/node_modules/uncss/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/async/node_modules/lodash/throttle.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /Users/me/project/node_modules/gulp-uncss/node_modules/uncss/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/async/node_modules/lodash/throttle.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/project/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

What/How can I solve that?

Comment: Can you type `node -v` in console and tell me your Node version?

Comment: From your stack trace, it looks like `node -v v0.10.31` which is very outdated. Try updating your Node.js install.